# using %D in constant to send variable

Tags: php, variables, constants

I remember seeing somewhere using %D or something similar to declare constant where the value of %D is supplied while calling the constant.

```
define("EVENT_DATE","The event date is %D");
```

Any information on this, how does it work please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) and [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf).

Example:

```
define('EVENT_DATE', 'The event date is %s.');
echo sprintf(EVENT_DATE, 'tomorrow morning');
```

The above will display:

```
The event date is tomorrow morning.
```

If all you want to do is print, and you're absolutely sure that the string does not need [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) applied to it, then you can use `printf()` directly. It works just like `sprintf()`, but it echoes the result instead of returning it.

---

As Mel points out while downvoting, `%D` is indeed a [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) format. Check that out as well and check [Mel's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139502/using-d-in-constant-to-send-variable/6139542#answer-6139675) of how to use it.

Comment: Weird voting going on here. %D is specifically mentioned in the title and means nothing to sprintf() - in fact misspelled as %d gives totally unexpected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare constants for your program in php:

```
define("CONSTANT_EXAMPLE", 2);
echo CONSTANT_EXAMPLE * CONSTANT_EXAMPLE;
```

This will echo 4.

Answer (score 1):

The specific %D is used in strftime:

```
<?php
define('EVENT_DATE', 'The event date is %D');
$eventDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 31);
echo strftime(EVENT_DATE, $eventDate);
?>
```

Gives: `The event date is 05/31/11`

Comment: Thanks Mel. I mentioned %D but I was not specific about date only. The whole thing was unintentional, I wanted something like %s but was not remembering all the short forms of %. Thank you nonetheless to clarify me for %D as well. I gave an upvote to you.